# Server Error in Application when trying to publish web app. Invalid object name 'dbo.Employees'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service, publish

I'm trying to publish my web app with my database with Azure but I'm running into this error:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Employee'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 
'dbo.Employee'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web 
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Here are my connection strings:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HolidayTracker-20190122013056.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-HolidayTracker-20190122013056;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="LotusWorksEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.HolidayTrackerModel.csdl|res://*/Models.HolidayTrackerModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.HolidayTrackerModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-LAKNQGQ\CONORSQL;initial catalog=LotusWorks;user id=sa;password={"mypassword"};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I'm not sure if I used these correctly when publishing as this is my first web app. It does get published but anytime I use a page which uses the database I get an error.

Comment: What database you use? Azure SQL or Local SQL?

Comment: I am using Local SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 
>   'dbo.Employee'.

This error means that EF uses an object (most likely a table) named dbo.Employee, which does not exist in the database.

**Check your database and verify whether that table exists**, or that you should be using a different table name.

Also, according to your description, the connection strings you provided are **all local Sql database**. As you want to publish to azure and view the page which uses the database, you need to use the Azure Sql Database to provide data. Here is a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) you could refer to.

After setting up Azure sql database, select `Use this connection string at runtime(update destination web.config)` option, so it will use the azure sql db connectionstring.

[image]

Comment: Yes it exist. I used database first to create the web app. I think it may be pointing to the wrong database!! I have used the azure connection strings in the publish window box.

Comment: It hasn't just yet! If I am using local SQL databases? How do I connect them with Azure? using vs2013 btw

Comment: use local database to connect with azure? It impossible.

Comment: Would I have to alter the connections strings themselves? The default connection string works with azure, its just the other one that is giving me trouble

Comment: Here is a article about [Publish MVC Database First site to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure) you could refer to.

Comment: So just to clarify, If I have a database built in SSMS, which I use on my app, I cannot deploy to Azure??

Comment: Yes I have been using that tutorial but I get no publish database box to appear!!

Comment: You could try to [Migrate SQL Server Database To Azure SQL Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/migrate-a-sql-server-database-to-azure-sql-server/).

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help Joey

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: Just one quick question before you go. I have the database on azure now, how would I connect it to my web app?

Comment: As the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure) I provided before, you configure database in [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFZVC.png).